# Angularjs, replace html content when angular is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-seo

I have an angular app with a page and dynamic content.
I use ui router for routing.

I want user to see static html which server side rendering will return it, and when angular is loaded, change html content with ur router templates.

sample static html is:

```
<div ui-view>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
<div>
```

sample ui router template is:

```
<div>
  <div>{{myModel}}</div>
  <p>{{myModel2}}</p>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
<div>
```

My aims:

1. User should see some static html, before dynamic content is loaded. Dynamic content will replace it.
2. Search engines should track static files, not something like `<p>{{myModel2}}</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make static content visible before ui-router is resolved like this:

```
<ui-view>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</ui-view>
```

Using `ui-view` as custom tag will render inner HTML without any changes to it, however when route is resolved this content will be replaced with actual route template.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. I tried it as <div ui-view></div> in first place, it didn't work. When I try your explanation it worked.